# Error while creating ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.ExtensionsConfigurableWroManagerFactory

Tags: wro4j

Currently I am working in a web app proyect that involves Java, javascript, css (compass). I am trying to configure a **runtime solution** that merges all *.js and *.scss into a single file. I am following the guidelines explained in the [Wro4j site](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/ConfigurableWroManagerFactory) but still I get the following error:

```
2014-12-16 12:59:00,154 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR  ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory -  Using XmlModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using XmlModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: XmlModelFactory Cannot build model from XML Using GroovyModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using GroovyModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: GroovyModelFactory Invalid model found! Using JsonModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using JsonModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: JsonModelFactory Invalid model found!
2014-12-16 12:59:00,155 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR  ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory - Error while creating the model
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot create model using any of provided factories
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory.create(SmartWroModelFactory.java:194)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory.create(SmartWroModelFactory.java:36)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.create(FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.java:48)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.create(FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.java:22)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.access$101(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:19)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory$1.initialize(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:32)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory$1.initialize(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:29)
    at ro.isdc.wro.util.LazyInitializer.get(LazyInitializer.java:33)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.create(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:42)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.create(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:19)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.ModelTransformerFactory.create(ModelTransformerFactory.java:55)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.ModelTransformerFactory.create(ModelTransformerFactory.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.create(DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.java:53)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.create(DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.java:25)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.GroupsProcessor.process(GroupsProcessor.java:65)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:40)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:22)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.get(AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:52)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.serveProcessedBundle(WroManager.java:182)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.process(WroManager.java:134)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.processRequest(WroFilter.java:374)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.doFilter(WroFilter.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at de.tetralog.pqa.auth.valve.PQACBSamlLoginValve.invoke(PQACBSamlLoginValve.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-12-16 12:59:00,157 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN   ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory - Couldn't load new model, reusing last Valid Model!
2014-12-16 12:59:00,160 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] INFO   com.tetralog.optimize4.servlets.ErrorPageServlet - Error page servlet initialized with the following options: errorPage=/WEB-INF/pages/error/error.jsp, showStackTrace=true
2014-12-16 12:59:00,162 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR  com.tetralog.optimize4.servlets.ErrorPageServlet - Unhandled error in web application: incident id 014a52f73440-6152ec8b, HTTP status code 404 (Not Found), error message: "/bestInvest/wro/all.js", servlet: default, request URI: "/bestInvest/wro/all.js" (referer: "http://localhost:8080/bestInvest/customerSelection.do")
2014-12-16 13:07:27,975 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR  ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory -  Using XmlModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using XmlModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: XmlModelFactory Cannot build model from XML Using GroovyModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using GroovyModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: GroovyModelFactory Invalid model found! Using JsonModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using JsonModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: JsonModelFactory Invalid model found!
2014-12-16 13:07:27,976 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR  ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory - Error while creating the model
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot create model using any of provided factories
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory.create(SmartWroModelFactory.java:194)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory.create(SmartWroModelFactory.java:36)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.create(FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.java:48)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.create(FallbackAwareWroModelFactory.java:22)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.access$101(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:19)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory$1.initialize(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:32)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory$1.initialize(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:29)
    at ro.isdc.wro.util.LazyInitializer.get(LazyInitializer.java:33)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.create(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:42)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.create(InMemoryCacheableWroModelFactory.java:19)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.ModelTransformerFactory.create(ModelTransformerFactory.java:55)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.ModelTransformerFactory.create(ModelTransformerFactory.java:27)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.create(DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.java:53)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.create(DefaultWroModelFactoryDecorator.java:25)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.GroupsProcessor.process(GroupsProcessor.java:65)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:40)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:22)
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.get(AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:52)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.serveProcessedBundle(WroManager.java:182)
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.process(WroManager.java:134)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.processRequest(WroFilter.java:374)
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.doFilter(WroFilter.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at de.tetralog.pqa.auth.valve.PQACBSamlLoginValve.invoke(PQACBSamlLoginValve.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-12-16 13:07:27,976 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] WARN   ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory - Couldn't load new model, reusing last Valid Model!
```

I added the following dependencies to my pom.xml file:

```
    <!-- ====================================================================================== -->
        <!-- PROJECT DEPENDENCIES -->
        <!-- ====================================================================================== -->
        <dependencies>

    <!-- WRO4J -->
            <dependency>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>rhino</groupId>
      <artifactId>js</artifactId>
      <version>1.7R2</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

I create the wro.properties file inside the WEF-INF directory:

```
<pre><code>
cacheUpdatePeriod=0

modelUpdatePeriod=0
debug=true
disableCache=false
minimizeEnabled=false
gzipResources=true
ignoreMissingResources=true
jmxEnabled=true

managerFactoryClassName=ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.ExtensionsConfigurableWroManagerFactory
preProcessors=semicolonAppender,sassCss,cssImport
postProcessors=cssVariables
uriLocators=servletContext,uri,classpath

</code></pre>
```

and also the wro.xml in the same directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isdc.ro/wro wro.xsd">

  <group name="all">
         <js>/js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/jquery.ie-select-width.js</js>

         <js>/js/lib/jquery.blockUI.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/stringPrototypeFix.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/jquery.tooltipster.min.js</js>
         <js>/js/constants.js</js>
         <js>/js/common.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/underscore-min.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/backbone-min.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom.min.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-de.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/datetime.control.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/arrayExtensions.js</js>
         <js>/js/lib/moment.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/numeral.min.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/numericInput.jquery.plugin.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/defaultText.jquery.plugin.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/dialog.jquery.plugin.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/dataTracker.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/editableCombobox.jquery.plugin.js</js>
         <js>/js/plugins/textField.utils.jQuery.plugin.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/common.models.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/permissionKeys.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/common.errorCodes.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/categoryModel.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/predicates.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/filterCondition.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/common/*.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/pageResultModel.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/searchResultModel.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/paginatedModel.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/chart.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/message.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/dataTrackerFunction.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/common/workflow/*.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/common/workflow/*.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/user.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/advisor.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/distribution.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/charts/chartDistribution.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/charts/chart.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/money.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/customer.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/allocation.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/products/product.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/products/productInstance.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/products/productLine.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/recommendation/portfolioPositions.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customer-selection/customerSearch.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerReports/reportType.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerReports/report.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerReports/customerReports.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customer-selection/newCustomer.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerProfileChanges/profileChanges.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerProfileChanges/customerProfileChanges.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerOverview/currentAllocation.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/documentation/documentation.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/documentation/tax.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/documentation/taxReduction.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/orderform/orderformOrderPosition.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/orderform/orderformDeposit.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/orderform/orderform.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerSelection/customerSelectionPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerSelection/customerSearch.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerSelection/newCustomer.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerProfile/customerProfilePage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerProfile/customerProfileByLaw.view.js</js>

         <js>/js/views/customerReports/customerReportRow.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerReports/customerReportsTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerReports/customerReportsPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerProfileChanges/customerProfileChangesPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerProfileChanges/customerProfileChangesRow.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerProfileChanges/customerProfileChangesTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/instrumentCategory.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/instrumentInfo.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/position.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/role.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/portfolioNode.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/portfolio.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/modelPortfolio.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/deposit.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/account.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/investmentParameters.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/accountClassification.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/manualCreatedAccount.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/instrumentQuantity.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/depotsPageSummaryTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/depotsPageSummaryAccountTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/depotsPage.view.js</js>

         <js>/js/views/portfolios/combination.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/analysis.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/investmentInfo.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/holistic.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/accountClassificationTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/instrumentTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/thirdPartyComponents.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/portfolios/investmentSummaryTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/start/start.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerOverview/assetOverview.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/customerOverview/nodeOverview.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerOverview/depotDetails.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerOverview/customerOverviewRow.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerOverview/customerOverviewTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/customerOverview/customerOverviewPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/documentation/documentationPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/documentation/documentationTaxes.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/documentation/documentationVacationReplacement.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/documentation/documentationFactsheetsAndKid.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/orderform/orderformPosition.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/orderform/orderformDepositTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/orderform/orderformDeposit.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/orderform/orderformPage.view.js</js>

         <js>/js/views/model-allocation/modelAllocation.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/model-allocation/modelPortfolioList.view.js</js>

         <js>/js/views/model-allocation/modelAllocationTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/model-allocation/modelAllocationRow.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/model-allocation/positionAllocation.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/model-allocation/asset-allocation.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/model-allocation/current-asset-allocation.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/product-selection/product-selection.module.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/model-allocation/automatic-allocation.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-selection/productSelectionPositionRow.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-selection/productSelectionTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-selection/productSelectionPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-selection/savingsPlanSelection.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-selection/MifidCellGenerator.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-selection/recursiveHeader.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/needs/focusPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/needs/needs.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/needs/needs-product-selection.model.js</js>

         <js>/js/views/logout/logout.view.js</js>

         <js>/js/views/product-search/productSearchTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-search/hitList.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/product-search/expandable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/domain/portfolios/link.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/recommendationPortfolioPositions/recommendationPortfolioPositionsPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/transactions/transactionsPage.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/transactions/transactionsSummaryTable.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/transactions/transactionsTableRow.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/transaction/reallocationItem.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/models/transaction/transaction.model.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/user-profile/user-profile.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/user-profile/userProfile.view.js</js>
         <js>/js/views/sessions/sessions.js</js>
  </group>

<group name="allcss">
<css>/scss/pages/_login.scss</css>

<css>/scss/pages/_customerSearch.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_customerInfo.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_customerProfile.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_customerReports.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_customerProfileChanges.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_customerOverview.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_workflow.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_portfolios.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_modelAllocation.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_productSelection.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_needs.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_transactions.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_startPage.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_documentationPage.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_orderformPage.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_recommendation.scss</css>
<css>/scss/pages/_userProfile.scss</css>
</group>




</groups>
```

Finally in my web.xml I have:

```
<!-- ===================================================================================== -->
    <!--  FILTERS                                                                              -->
    <!-- ===================================================================================== -->

    <!--  Wro4j  -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
...

<!-- ===================================================================================== -->
    <!--  FILTER MAPPINGS                                                                      -->
    <!-- ===================================================================================== -->
<!--  Wro4j  -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

...
```

am I doing something wrong? Is there something missing?

---

I was using version 1.4.7 with ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.ExtensionsConfigurableWroManagerFactory . Now I am trying with version 1.7.7 and ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory but still get the same error. The stack trace is a bit different, but that's something expected since I am using a different factory:

```
2014-12-17 17:09:32,604 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR  ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory -  Using XmlModelFactory for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using XmlModelFactory failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: XmlModelFactory Cannot build model from XML: Invalid resource requested: /WEB-INF/wro.xml Using LazyWroModelFactoryDecorator for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using LazyWroModelFactoryDecorator failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: LazyWroModelFactoryDecorator Invalid model found! Using LazyWroModelFactoryDecorator for model creation..
[FAIL] Model creation using LazyWroModelFactoryDecorator failed. Trying another ...
[FAIL] Exception occured while building the model using: LazyWroModelFactoryDecorator Invalid model found!
2014-12-17 17:09:32,605 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR  ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.FallbackAwareWroModelFactory - Error while creating the model
ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Cannot create model using any of provided factories
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory.create(SmartWroModelFactory.java:209)
    at ro.isdc.wro.extensions.model.factory.SmartWroModelFactory.create(SmartWroModelFactory.java:38)
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.factory.WroModelFactoryDecorator.create(WroModelFactoryDecorator.java:27)
```

Regarding the location of the wro.xml, I have the following project tree under eclipse:

```
project_root
 +src
   +main
     +WEB-INF
       -web.xml
       -wro.properties
       -wro.xml
```

Comment: What wro4j.version are you using? 
What is the location of your wro.xml?
Also, use the following managerFactoryClassName:
wroManagerFactory=ro.isdc.wro.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory